# Custom BCS indexing connector with changelog inremental crawl is not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, bcs, crawling

Custom BCS indexing connector with changelog inremental crawl is not working properly

I am writing a custom indexing connector using changelog incremental crawl approach.
I'm using sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625800%28v=office.14%29.aspx and trying to change it for me.

My model has next stereotypes: IdEnumerator, ChangedIdEnumerator, DeletedIdEnumerator, SpecificFinder, Finder, StreamAccessor

If I'm starting full crawl, IdEnumerator, ChangedIdEnumerator, DeletedIdEnumerator will be called.

> > First problem: the SpecificFinder is not called.

If I'm starting incremental crawl, ChangedIdEnumerator and DeletedIdEnumerator will be called.

DeletedIdEnumerator is working: items with deleted ids are deleted from the index.

> > Second problem: ChangedIdEnumerator is not working. Nothing happens after I returned the changed ids.

There are now errors in the crowl log.

My model is here:

```
<Model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="MyFileModel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog">
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Name="MyFileSystem" Type="Custom">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="SystemUtilityTypeName" Type="System.String">MyFileConnector.MyFileConnector, MyFileConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15865f58b9878bf8</Property>
        <Property Name="SystemUtilityInstallDate" Type="System.DateTime">2013-01-01 00:00:00Z</Property>
        <Property Name="InputUriProcessor" Type="System.String">MyFileConnector.MyFileLobUri, MyFileConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15865f58b9878bf8</Property>
        <Property Name="OutputUriProcessor" Type="System.String">MyFileConnector.MyFileNamingContainer, MyFileConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15865f58b9878bf8</Property>
      </Properties>
      <LobSystemInstances>
        <LobSystemInstance Name="MyFileConnector_instance">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="AuthenticationType" Type="System.String">Credentials</Property>
         </Properties>
        </LobSystemInstance>
      </LobSystemInstances>
  <Entities>
    <Entity Name="MyFolder" Namespace="MyFileConnector" Version="1.0.0.1">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="Title" Type="System.String">Name</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Identifiers>
        <Identifier Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" />
      </Identifiers>

      <Methods>
        <!--        IdEnumerator          -->
        <Method Name="ReadAllIds" DefaultDisplayName="ReadAllIds" IsStatic="false">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="returnIds" Direction="Return">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="Nodes" TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" IsCollection="true">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="IdEnumerator" Name="ReadAllIds" DefaultDisplayName="ReadAllIds" ReturnParameterName="returnIds" Default="true">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="RootFinder" Type="System.String">true</Property>
              </Properties>
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!--        ChangedIdEnumerator          -->
        <Method Name="ReadIncrementalList" IsStatic="false">
          <FilterDescriptors>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String">x</Property>
              </Properties>
            </FilterDescriptor>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="Timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
          </FilterDescriptors>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="lastCrawlDate" Direction="InOut">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="LastCrawlDate" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                <Interpretation>
                  <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
                </Interpretation>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="returnIds" Direction="Return">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Name="ReadIncrementalListInstance" Type="ChangedIdEnumerator" ReturnParameterName="returnIds" Default="true">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <!--        DeletedIdEnumerator          -->
        <Method Name="ReadDeletedIncrementalList" IsStatic="false" DefaultDisplayName="ReadDeletedIncrementalList">
          <FilterDescriptors>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String">x</Property>
              </Properties>
            </FilterDescriptor>
            <FilterDescriptor Name="Timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
          </FilterDescriptors>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="LastCrawlDate" Direction="InOut">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="LastCrawlDate" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                <Interpretation>
                  <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
                </Interpretation>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="deletedIds" Direction="Return">
              <TypeDescriptor  TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Name="ReadDeletedIncrementalListInstance" Type="DeletedIdEnumerator" ReturnParameterName="deletedIds">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>

        <!--        Finder          -->
        <Method Name="ReadAllItems" DefaultDisplayName="ReadAllItems" IsStatic="false">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="returnAllItems" Direction="Return">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType[]" Name="Nodes" IsCollection="true" >
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Name" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Title" />
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Path" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="Finder" Name="ReadAllItems" DefaultDisplayName="ReadAllItems" ReturnParameterName="returnAllItems" Default="true" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="Nodes" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>

        <!--        SpecificFinder          -->
        <Method Name="ReadItem" DefaultDisplayName="ReadItem" IsStatic="false">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="In" Name="ID">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" />
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="returnParameter">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.DynamicType" Name="Node">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Title" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Author" />
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="SpecificFinder" ReturnParameterName="returnParameter" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="Node" Default="true" Name="ReadItem" DefaultDisplayName="ReadItem"  ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0">
              <AccessControlList>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users">
                  <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
                </AccessControlEntry>
                <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT AUTHORITY\System">
                  <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions"/>
                </AccessControlEntry>
              </AccessControlList>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
      </Methods>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
</LobSystem>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you manage to get it sorted out?